# Can't remove whitespaces (after splitting div up with lettering.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got some divs, which I split up with [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/). What this does is just splitting up an element into `<span>`s containing the single characters.

When I got a string with multiple words like "Hello World!", lettering.js will create a separate span for the space between the words. That span won't have a width, since its "empty" → there's no space between the words.

So theoretically I should be able to select those "empty" spans with `span:blank` (and manually setting a width for the space) since :blank selects whitespace aswell.
That didn't work tho.

So I tried using JavaScript, but even that failed.

I tried several methods:

```
$("span[class^='char']").each(function(){
  // method 1:
  this.innerHTML.trim();

  // method 2:
  $(this).text().trim(); 

  // method 3:
  $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '');

  // method 4:
  $(this).text().replace(' ', '');
});
```

But all of those methods failed.

The selector isn't the problem. It selects every span I want it to.

Another method would just be to set a `min-width` for every span, which is pretty shabby tho and isn't always working nicely.

Anyone got an idea how I can get those "empty" `<span>`s to show as spaces?

---

[Here's a link](https://tglaus.com/portfolio/index.php) with a live example of the problem if you want to check it out.

---

**Update:** Removing `display:inline-block` from the span elements makes the space show up. I can't remove it tho, since the transform animation stops working properly without it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :empty pseudo selector and  add a space via content in CSS;

```css
span:empty{
   content:' ';
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<span>A</span>
<span></span>
<span>B</span>
```

Comment: I can't use :empty since the span contains a space and isnt empty. :empty just checks for **truly** empty elements.

Comment: Sorry - I thought you were clearing those with trim() - If there is a space in the span - why can't you just set the display to inline-block ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried, but all of the above methods I mentioned failed :/ The span elements already got `display:inline-block` but still the space is not showing.

Comment: Thanks for the `display:inline-block` comment. I tried removing the property and now the space shows up. Does that make any sense? :D Still I can't just not use `display:inline-block`, since the transform animations stops working then.

Comment: I guess its now just showing the span as part of normal DOM flow - happy to have helped in some small way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  You can use letter-spacing to remove white space between the text.

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div.a {
      width: auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      letter-spacing:0px
    }

    div.b {
      width: 150px;
      border: 1px solid black;  
    }

    div.c {
      width: 50%;
      border: 1px solid black;  
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>The width Property</h1>

    <h2>width: auto (default)</h2>
    <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</div>



    </body>
    </html>
```